# Drop down autocomplete menu for each word types in text box, once user types "#"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if this is way too complicated.

In HTML I have a textbox (< input>), and in Javascript I have a working method called getWords(prefix) which returns an array of words that match that prefix, for example

```
getWords("")
```

returns ["sofa","chair","planet","colombia","century"]

```
getWords("c")
```

returns ["car","colombia","century"], whereas

```
 getWords["co"]
```

only returns [colombia]

I have a textbox and I Want to be able to display a dropdown whenever the user types # according to what they type after the "#"

for example

> I want to go to C

doesn't do anything

> I want to go to #

entire drop down menu appears

> I want to go to #c

drop down menu narrows down to only "car" "colombia" "century"

and so on.

I know my getWords method is helpful, But how can I do the drop down menu part?

what I have so far:

```
<input id="textField1"  type="text" onkeypress="function1(event)">
  <br>
```

in javascript

```
function function1(e) {
    var keyPressed = e.key;
    if (keyPressed == "#") {
       bring drop down menu somehow
}
```

Comment: Are you on a React component?

Comment: not really. I'm trying to use react but I am not react component

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react:

```js
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        show_suggestion:false,
        suggestions:[]
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}
handleChange(el,{value}){
    if(value){
        if(value.chartAt(0)=="#"){
            //call your helper function to get list of suggestions
            this.setState({
                show_suggestion : true,
                suggestions : helper_list,
                value : value
            })
        }else{
            this.setState({
                show_suggestion : false,
                suggestions : [],
                value : value
            })
        }
    }
}
selectionCallback(value){
    this.setState({
        show_suggestion:false,
        suggestions : [],
        value : value
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}/>
        {this.state.show_suggestion&&<CustomDropDown 
            list={this.state.suggestions}
            selectionCallback={this.selectionCallback}
        />}
    )
}
```

CustomDropDown:

```js
export default const Cop = (props) => {
    return(
        {props.list.map((item, index)=>{
            return <span key={index} onClick={()=>props.selectionCallback(item)}>{item}</span>
        })
    )
}
```

hope its what you need